# Set Pull Request polices based on raising user(s)

Tags: azure-devops

I want to assign required approvers based on who raises a PR and not what the PR is on.

I have a set of repos that is maintained by multiple teams. I want to have a team be automatically added as required reviewers based on the user making the PR.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Out of the box, to have it created on Pull Request creation, looks like No.  You could log a feature request on developer community.  I could see this being achievable by adding a build validation pipeline that uses the API to add the required approvers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

It's **possible**. But the process would be very complex since Azure Devops doesn't have such out-of-box feature, so we have to use `Build Validation/Rest API/PS` to achieve what you want.

1.Create a Classic Build pipeline with PS task.

2.Add [build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) in branch policy. So this pipeline will run first if anyone raises a PR.

3.If one pipeline is triggered by PR, we can access the variables like `$(Build.Repository.ID)`,`$(Build.RequestedFor)`(the user making the PR),`$(Build.RequestedForEmail)`(the user's email). See [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables).

4.Use [Teams-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20teams?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get list of teams in current project. You now have the TeamIDs, you now know the corresponding TeamIDs the user belongs to.

5.Use powershell [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7) or if statement to dynamically define the team the user belongs to.

```
switch ("$(Build.RequestedFor)")
{
    "User1" {$TeamID="xxxx"; Break}
    "User2" {$TeamID="xxxx"; Break}
    "User3" {$TeamID="xxxx"; Break}
    Default {
        "No matches"
    }
}
```

6.Use [Configurations-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to list the ConfigurationIDs in this project. (You may also need to determine the correct ConfigurationID by SourceRepo and SourceBranch)

7.Then use [Configuration-Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update the branch policy to define required approvers dynamically.

The request body would look like this:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "isBlocking": true,
  "type": {
    "id": "fd2167ab-b0be-447a-8ec8-39368250530e"
  },
  "settings": {
    "requiredReviewerIds": [
      "{replace it with corresponding TeamID}"
    ],
    "filenamePatterns": [],
    "addedFilesOnly": false,
    "scope": [
      {
        "repositoryId": "{replace it with your repoID in step3}",
        "refName": "refs/heads/master",
        "matchKind": "exact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can do step5 and step7 in same PS task.